# How to count the number of words that are palindromes in a string?

Tags: c, string, palindrome

I'm obviously new to the forums and need some help. I'm writing a program that shows the number of vowels, words, and palindromes within a sentence. I'm at the end of my rope and am completely lost.

I'm using C and I'm trying to loop through the words within an input and then determine how many palindromes are in the sentence, which are then stored within a counter and printed later within the main method, but I require assistance on creating said loop in order properly store the values in the counter.

Here is what I have so far(I'm specifically looking at `int is_palindrome(char my_sen[])`)

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <ctype.h>
        #define SENTENCE 256


        int main(void){

        char my_sen[SENTENCE],*s; //String that containts at most 256 as well as a pointer
        int words = 1, count = 0, pal_count= 0; //Integer variables being defined
        int i,vowel = 0, length;  //More definitions
        printf("Enter a sentence: ");//Input sentence
        gets(my_sen);//Receives and processes input
        length = strlen(my_sen); //Stores the length of the input within length

        for(i=0;my_sen[i] != '\0'; i++){
            if(my_sen[i]=='a' || my_sen[i]=='e' || my_sen[i]=='i' || my_sen[i]=='o' || my_sen[i]=='u' || //Loop that states if the input contains any of the following
               my_sen[i]=='A' || my_sen[i]=='E' || my_sen[i]=='I' || my_sen[i]=='O' || my_sen[i]=='U')   //characters(in this case, vowels), then it shall be
               {                                                                                         //stored to be later printed
                   vowel++;
               }


            if(my_sen[i]==' ' || my_sen[i]=='!' || my_sen[i]=='.' || my_sen[i]==',' || my_sen[i]==';' || //Similar to the vowel loop, but this time
                my_sen[i]=='?')                                                                          //if the following characters are scanned within the input
                {                                                                                        //then the length of the characters within the input is
                    length--;                                                                            //subtracted
        }
        }

        for(s = my_sen; *s != '\0'; s++){ //Loop that stores the number of words typed after
            if(*s == ' '){                //each following space
            count++;
        }
        }



        printf("The sentence entered is %u characters long.\n", length); //Simply prints the number of characters within the input
        printf("Number of words in the sentence: %d\n", count + 1); // Adding 1 to the count to keep track of the last word
        printf("Average length of a word in the input: %d\n", length/count);//Prints the average length of words in the input
        printf("Total Number of Vowels: %d\n", vowel);//Prints the number of vowels in the input
        printf("Average number of vowels: %d\n", vowel/count);//Prints the average number of vowels within the input
        printf("Number of words that contain at least 3 vowels: %d\n",vowel_count(my_sen));//Prints number of words that contain at least 3 vowels
        printf("Number of words that are palindomes: %d\n", is_palindrome(my_sen));
        return 0;
        }

        int vowel_count(char my_sen[])
        {
          int wcount = 0; 
          int vcount = 0; 
          int i = 0;
          int ch;
          while ((ch = my_sen[i++]) != '\0')
          {
            if (isspace(ch) || !isalpha(ch))
            {
              wcount += vcount >= 3; 
              vcount = 0; 
              continue;

            if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", ch) != NULL) 
            {
              ++vcount; 
            }
          }

          wcount += vcount >= 3; // add 1 to wcount if vcount >= 3
          return wcount;
        }


int is_palindrome(char my_sen[]){
  int begin, middle, end, length = 0, result = 0, pal = 0; //variables representing the string length, beginning, middle, and end of string

   while ( my_sen[length] != '\0' ) //loop to define and initialize variables
      length++;

   end = length - 1; //end is the end of the length
   middle = length/2;//middle is half the length

   for( begin = 0 ; begin < middle ; begin++ )
   {
      if ( my_sen[begin] != my_sen[end] ) //if the beginning isn't equal to the end, then it's not a palindrome
      {
        result += pal;
         pal = 0;
         continue;
      }
      end--;
   }
   if( begin == middle ) //if the beginning is the same as the middle, its a palindrome
      pal++;
      result += pal;
      return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm also aware that I'm missing a parenthesis at the end of vowel_count, for some reason it didn't transfer.

Comment: I wouldn't bother reversing the string, but rather just work from both ends towards the middle and compare characters.  But usually palindrome sentences are figured with blanks omitted.  You can do that on the fly (skip over blanks as you compare), or pre-process the string to remove blanks.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean? I'm pretty beginner to C and programming in general. This brain-teaser has bested me for a few days now and I need any visual help that one can give.

Comment: You've created quite a brain-teaser for yourself -- hard for me to follow.  Start by adding comments explaining what each input and output is for each routine, what's conceptually in each variable, what your loops are doing, etc.  If you can't write the comments then you can't write the code.

Comment: Note that you say "number of words that are palindromes" but you're processing the entire sentence as one piece.  So you're not going to count palindromic words (that I can see).  At best (after many fixes) the code might tell you if the overall sentence is a palindrome.

Comment: I'm getting rid of the reverse function then, as for the actual palindrome function, I know that I have to create a loop to go through the string itself and stop after each space to know that a word is being typed as well as be able to realize whether or not that it's a palindrome.

Comment: I just edited the is_palindrome function to process the beginning, middle and end of the string. But from here this is where I've met my end. I don't know how to proceed any further.

Comment: You're getting close.  First off, use `strlen` to get string length -- clearer than doing your own loop.  Inside the `for` loop you should `break` if the characters are not equal -- kick yourself out of the loop.  The other stuff inside that `if` statement makes no sense.  I don't see the sense in having both "pal" and "result" -- you'll only ever detect one palindrome with that code.  You should (almost) always use `{}` characters for the body of an `if`, for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Code below has been tested. Please correct or downvote as needed. Apologies if formatting for code is invalid.
I am going to give you an example that I just put together, off the top of my head.
It might not be exactly in line with your requirements, but it should get you started.
I will then explain how my code works, and give you some pointers to modify your code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i,vowels,pals,words;
vowels=words=pals=i=0;
long max=1024;
char *sentence=malloc(sizeof(char)*max);
printf("sentence:");
fgets(sentence,max,stdin);
if (sentence[strlen(sentence)-1]=='\n')
{
sentence[strlen(sentence)-1]='\0';
}
for (i=0;i<=strlen(sentence);i++)
{
char x;
x=sentence[i];
switch (x)
{
case 'a':
case 'A':
case 'e':
case 'E':
case 'i':
case 'I':
case 'o':
case 'O':
case 'u':
case 'U':
vowels+=1;
}
if ((x==' '||x=='\0') && i>0 && sentence[i-1]!=' ')
{
words+=1;
}
if (i>0 && (x=='\0'||x==' '))
{
char *lastchar,*pos,*word;
lastchar=sentence+i;
pos=(sentence+i)-1;
while (*pos!=' ' && pos!=sentence)
{
pos--;
if (*pos==' ')
{
pos++;
break;
}
}
word=strndup(pos,lastchar-pos);
if (isSameStringReversed(word)==0)
{
pals+=1;
}
free(word);
} //if on space for pal
} //for
printf("vowels:%d words:%d pals:%d\n",vowels,words,pals);
free(sentence);
}

int isSameStringReversed(char *word)
{
int i;
char destword[strlen(word)+1];
int j;
for (i=strlen(word)-1,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++)
{
destword[j]=word[i];
}
return strncmp(word,destword,strlen(word));
}
</pre>
```

Now some code descriptions.

```
//here are our includes. nothing special.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
//defines
int i,vowels,pals,words;
long max;
//set all to zero. (an empty sentence has no words.)
vowels=words=pals=i=0;
//max is the largest sentence you can enter
max=1024;
//allocate space for the sentence in memory.
char *sentence=malloc(sizeof(char)*max);
//prompt for sentence
printf("sentence:");
//read characters from stdin, making sure that only the first 1023 characters are read. (fgets removes the last character(s) if it is greater or equal to the provided limit. e.g. providing 1024 means that all characters past character 1023 are removed, and a \0 is appended to sentence.)
fgets(sentence,max,stdin);
//check last character of sentence for \n character, as some calls leave newlines attached.
if (sentence[strlen(sentence)-1]=='\n')
{
//set the last character to \0 if newline found. \0 terminates strings in c.
sentence[strlen(sentence)-1]='\0';
}
//move through every character in the sentence, including the terminating \0 character. This way, we make sure we pass every word and character provided, and we don't have to check at the end of loops for remaining characters.
for (i=0;i<=strlen(sentence);i++)
{
//defines for this for loop
char x;
//pull the current character from sentence. this way, we don't ahve to do sentence[i] each time.
x=sentence[i];
//switch is like an extended if statement with lots of possible branches.
switch (x)
{
//if x, the current character, equals 'a'
case 'a':
//if x, the current character, equals uppercase 'A'
case 'A':
//etc for the rest of the variables (excluding the sometimes cases of 'y')
case 'e':
case 'E':
case 'i':
case 'I':
case 'o':
case 'O':
case 'u':
case 'U':
//if x equals any of the above letters, then
//we add one to vowels, since our current letter is a vowel.
vowels+=1;
}
//if our current character is a space character, or a \0, meaning the end of our sentence string,
//and we are not on our first character, (because our sentence is not empty), and the character before our current character is not a space (because we don't count double spaces as words)
if ((x==' '||x=='\0') && i>0 && sentence[i-1]!=' ')
{
//it's a word, so add one to the words count
words+=1;
}
//again, if we are on a space or at the end of our string,
if (i>0 && (x=='\0'||x==' '))
{
//defines
char *lastchar,*pos,*word;
//lastchar is a pointer to where we are currently sitting (on the space or end character of the string)
lastchar=sentence+i;
//pos is a pointer to the previous character
//say we have
//A bunny likes racecar races.
//if we are on the space just after racecar, then lastchar points to the space, and pos points to the r in racecar
pos=(sentence+i)-1;
//while the character that pos points to isn't a space, and we aren't at the beginning of the string
while (*pos!=' ' && pos!=sentence)
{
//move the pointer pos back one character
pos--;
//if we're on a space, we've moved back before the previous word.
if (*pos==' ')
{
//we want to move pos to the first character of the preceding word.
pos++;
break;
}
}
//make a new copy of the current word, which we do by using strndup, analagus to (duplicate string with only n number of characters).
//we take the value of pos, and subtract it from lastchar, which gives us the length of the preceeding word.
//we used racecar as our example, so the space after racecar, minus the position of the r, gives us 7, which is the amount that strndup copys.
word=strndup(pos,lastchar-pos);
//if the function below returns 0
if (isSameStringReversed(word)==0)
{
//we've found a palindrome
pals+=1;
}
//free word, a.k.a. the chunk of memory we created for checking the last word as a palindrome.
free(word);
} //endif palindrome boundary check
} //endfor character in sentence loop
//print the character vowel and palindrome counts
printf("vowels:%d words:%d pals:%d\n",vowels,words,pals);
//free the sentence, as we're done with it.
free(sentence);
}

//function
//word is a pointer to char, or an array of characters. In this case word points to "word" defined above,
//or "racecar" from our example.
int isSameStringReversed(char *word)
{
//defines
//take the length of the provided word, and add a character to it for the \0, or ending character.
char destword[strlen(word)+1];
int i;
int j;
//set i to the number of the last character in word, and j to 0.
//move through the string, subtracting one from i and adding one to j.
for (i=strlen(word)-1,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++)
{
//move from right to left, assigning word to destword in reverse order.
//racecar would take the last r, assign it to the first slot in destword, the second to last a to the second position, and so on.
destword[j]=word[i];
//continue the loop
}
//see if the two reversed strings match, with strncmp.
return strncmp(word,destword,strlen(word));
}
```

Explanations.
Notice that we used pointers everywhere except in the last function.
This is for good reason.
Pointers are flexible, understandable, and allow mathmatical operations.
They are also quick and lend to code readability.
If you notice, we use these mathmatical properties when we subtract pos from lastchar.
This isn't as important when using chars, but when you get into other datatypes, moving from element to element will be quite helpful.
Also, if you notice, all of my variables are clearly labeled.
Again, this will help with code readability and maintainability.
If the code above was not enough, feel free to let me know, and I will do my best to elaborate further on a specific issue.

Comment: A little bit of formatting would go a long way to make your code more readable.